# How to sync between Cubes available in two Azure vm hosted on same data centers

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created two azure vm using trial version on same network(data centers). I tried to sync SSAS cube between one server to another. But i received error.. I tried to give access to the other servers login. but it is not available.

Ex: 1st azure vm login: CubeVm/devops
    2nd azure vm login: DBVM/devops. Both are in different domain. how to add the user in the other vm. or is it possible to create the same domain?

Comment: First - this should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow. Second: You really should provide more information about your network setup (same data center does not mean same network). We don't know how you deployed (classic vs arm, whether in a vnet, etc). This information is really important to help with diagnosis).

Comment: Sounds like both VMs are not domain joined? Do both have a local user with the same name and password? Is that user an SSAS admin on both?